# How to check connection .onion domain Tor URL in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, http, delphi-xe, indy, tor

How to check connection .onion domain Tor URL in Delphi XE?

example: http://1234567890abcdef.onion

result: 200 'Url exists' or 404 'Url does not exist' etc. via HTTP status codes.

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  http : TIdHttp;
  url : string;
  code : integer;
begin
  url := 'http://1234567890abcdef.onion';
  http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    try
      http.Head(url);
      code := http.ResponseCode;
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        code := http.ResponseCode; // or: code := E.ErrorCode;
    end;
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(code));
  finally
    http.Free();
  end;
end;
```

or

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  http : TIdHttp;
  url : string;
  code : integer;
begin
  url := 'http://1234567890abcdef.onion';
  http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    try
      http.Get(url, nil);
      code := http.ResponseCode;
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
        code := http.ResponseCode; // or: code := E.ErrorCode;
    end;
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(code));
  finally
    http.Free();
  end;
end;
```

but

always all results: '200' or 'connection timed out' for every Tor URL.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion):

> Such addresses are not actual DNS names, and the .onion TLD is not in
>   the Internet DNS root, but with the appropriate proxy software
>   installed, (...)

So to access .onion sites, configure Indy (TidHTTP) to use your proxy.